# Slicing with numpy in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have to work with `x`, `x[:, :-1]`, `x[:, :-2]`, etc. How to do this in a for loop?

```
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        y = x[:-i, :-j]
```

This works as desired if i and j are different than 0. But it fails if i or j is 0:

```
x[:, :-0]
```

is not `x[:, :]`.

What is the standard Numpy way to do this?

Is there better than `x[:x.shape[0]-i, :x.shape[1]-j]`?

TL;DR:

- `y[:-1]` is "all elements except the last one",
- `y[:-2]` is "all elements except the two last ones",
- but `y[:-0]` is NOT "all elements"

Comment: `x[:-i or None, :-j or None]` is ~1.40x faster, but less readable. Caching `x1,x2 = x.shape`, `x[:x1-i, :x2-j]` is equally fast.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to use the array-length `len` inside:

```
y[:len(y)-2] #is all except the last two
y[:len(y)-1] #is all except the last one
y[:len(y)-0] #is all
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to revert the order of iteration
in both loops (start from the **last** index, in **decreasing** order).

Then you can refer to a range of elements starting from *0* (no
number before the colon), ending at the index expressed by the loop
control variable (after the colon).

If you want "original" values from your original loops, compute them
as *10 - i* and *10 - j*.

To sum up, try the below code:

```
n = x.shape[0]
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(n, 0, -1):
        i2 = 10 - i
        j2 = 10 - j
        print(f'{i2}, {j2},  {i}, {j}\n{x[:i, :j]}')
```

Of course, for test purpose, use a smaller array, e.g. 10 * 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as the prior answer but I would just create a reverted version of the array. It could be memory-inefficient, but slightly more readable.

```py
x = np.arange(0, 25).reshape(5,5)
x_r = x[::-1, ::-1]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        y = x_r[i:, j:]
```